# Add a class under a module's namespace

Tags: ruby

I have the following class defined:

```
class ErrorMailer
end
```

I have a module, `Test`, under which I would like to add the above class. I've tried this in two ways:

```
# 1)
module Test
  class ErrorMailer < ::ErrorMailer; end
end

# 2)
module Test
  ErrorMailer = ::ErrorMailer
end
```

`1)` works as expected:

```
(rdb:1) Test.constants
[:ErrorMailer]
(rdb:1) Test::ErrorMailer
Test::ErrorMailer
```

However, `2)` doesn't: `Test` doesn't really have `ErrorMailer` under its namespace:

```
(rdb:1) Test.constants
[:ErrorMailer]
(rdb:1) Test::ErrorMailer
ErrorMailer
```

My question is, what's different between these 2 ways and how can I improve the second one to do what I expect it to do? I feel that only inheriting from a class doesn't look that good when I only want to add that class to the namespace.

P.S.: Of course I've tried `1)` and `2)` separately, not at the same time.

Comment: `class ErrorMailer < ::ErrorMailer` creates a new class `Test::ErrorMailer` with `::ErrorMailer` as its superclass whereas `ErrorMailer = ::ErrorMailer` just assigns the class `::ErrorMailer` to the constant `Test::ErrorMailer` without creating a new class. What's right and what's wrong depends on what you are trying to do. Why not just define the `ErrorMailer` class under `Test`? What's the point of having two `ErrorMailer` classes, i.e. a global one and a namespaced one?

Comment: The problem is that I need to have a generic class that should then be added under various namespaces. It's just the current setup and I can't change it. I need to have `ErrorMailer` namespaced by `Test` and several other modules.

Comment: In that case, 1) looks fine - `::ErrorMailer` is the generic superclass and `Test::ErrorMailer` is the specialized subclass.

Comment: What are your intentions with the second case because it seems you want to set a reference but you are making it a constant by the same name. Why not something like `@error_mailer = ::ErrorMailer` to make this a class instance variable. Although I prefer solution 1 and then you can just use `ErrorMailer` which will find `Test::ErrorMailer` inside the context of that module.

Comment: Okay, then I will go with the first approach. I thought there was a more "elegant" way of "importing" a class under a namespace.